# cannot integrate third party markdown extension into django-wiki markdown

Tags: python, django, markdown, semantic-web, django-wiki

I'm trying to use this extension: https://github.com/aleray/mdx_semanticdata with django-wiki's markdown but I am unable to get it to work (though it works in the python/django shell just fine). (django-wiki: https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki/)

Adding this line

`%%dc:author :: Sherry Turkle | Turkle's%% %%dc:title::Second Self%% was an early book on the social aspects of computation.`

to a django-wiki article (with mdx_semanticdata and semanticdata as extensions, see settings.py at the bottom) gives me

`<p><span>Turkle's</span> <span>Second Self</span> was an early book on the social aspects of computation."</p>`

Whereas doing

`import markdown
text = "%%dc:author :: Sherry Turkle | Turkle's%% %%dc:title::Second Self%% was an early book on the social aspects of computation."
html = markdown.markdown(text, ['semanticdata'])
print(html)`

In the python shell gives me:

`<p><span content="Sherry Turkle" property="dc:author">Turkle's</span> <span content="Second Self" property="dc:title">Second Self</span> was an early book on the social aspects of computation.</p>`

**Notice the spans from the python shell have content and property tags**. I would like to have the content and property tags in django-wiki. Can anyone help?

My settings.py:

`WIKI_MARKDOWN_KWARGS = {
    'extensions': [
        'semanticdata',
        'footnotes',
        'attr_list',
        'headerid',
        'extra',
        'mdx_semanticdata',
    ],
    'safe_mode': False,
}`

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how django-wiki sanitizes its inputs. Settings `WIKI_MARKDOWN_SANITIZE_HTML` to `False` solved the problem, but obviously this is not recommended.